# How to send text by template via url in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to send text to a view via template. I have two different types of clients that will be processed differently, to take advantage of code I put it in a single view and the specific part treated it with an `if else`.

In the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'client' 'prime' %}"> Client prime </a>
<a href="{% url 'client' 'free' %}"> Client </a>
```

In the urls.py

```
....
path('client/<str:typeclient>', Client, name='client'),
.....
```

In the view:

```
def Client(request, typeclient):
    ...
    if typeclient == "prime":
       ...
    else:
      ....
```

However I get the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'client' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['client\\/(?P<typeclient>[^/]+)$']
```

Apparently the text is not passing as a parameter that I inserted in the url.

In this sense, how can I pass a text from the template via url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 path('client/<typeclient>', Client, name='client'),


 <a href="{% url 'client' 'prime' %}"> Client prime </a>
 <a href="{% url 'client' 'free' %}"> Client </a>
```

Read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: is the error due to change in Django version. Before sometime, I used the same thing without having to write `typeclien='prime'` and just `prime` and it worked.Does that not work in Django 3.0 and above?